# How to dynamically modifying the PlotLine in Highcharts

Tags: dynamic, highcharts

Is there any way to dynamically modifying the PlotLine in Highcharts or Highstock?

I found there are both [addPlotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.addPlotLine%28%29) and removePlotLine in api. I don't want to delete the Plotline but just want to have a change.

Comment: At the bottom of [this page in the Highcharts API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts), there's a section labeled "Methods and properties for dynamically modifying the chart."  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, but can not located how to edit PlotLine. Any ideas?

Comment: What about [Redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw())?

Comment: In my understanding I don't need to redraw the chart, just want to dynamically change the position or color of PlotLine. I could remove PlotLine and draw it again using addPlotLine. But I feel should have a api to change the properties.

Comment: You need to read the documentation.  It states that you can change the data, *and it will redraw the chart by default automatically.*  Or, you can tell it not to redraw the data until you're done changing it.

Comment: You can use svg object and edit element by attr() function http://jsfiddle.net/HSK5N/1/

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan. I really don't understand why closing the question. I feel this question could help future visitors.

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan one more question. How could I change PlogLine label's postion using attr() function?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed, either. Highcharts is used by a large number of developers (including Stackoverflow's developers -- check out the charts on your own User reputation tab). I'd like to see an answer for this question -- please reopen.

As far as I can tell, there is no option to directly modify the position of a plotline using the highcharts API.

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear that one can specify the option to not auto-redraw the chart while adding/removing plotlines. Why the lack of capability when it comes to Plot Lines when most others options are packed with features?

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: why is this closed?